# Correcty handle Expectation failed (417) and change Expect100Continue in WCF client app

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, http-headers

My application is a C# Windows service that consumes a WCF service. When the first "Expectation failed (417)" error  occurs, I change both `ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue` and `ServicePoint.Expect100Continue` to `false`:

```
try
{
    //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; // If uncomment all work
    var svc = new ServiceClient();
    svc.GetData(); // first error
}
catch (ProtocolException pex)
{
    if (pex.Message.Contains("(417)"))
    {
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        var sp = ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(new Uri(@"http://addr.to.service/service.svc"));
        sp.Expect100Continue = false;

        var svc = new ServiceClient();
        svc.GetData(); // second same error
    }
}
```

However, the second call to the service also fails. But if I set `Expect100Continue` to `false` before any connection, communication with the service works correctly.

**Is this way correctly to handle `Expect100Continue` errors? I need the application adapts automatically without user action. What am I forgetting to do this work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the settings on `ServicePointManager` are treated as the default values applied on all NEW ServicePoints that are created after that point in the application's life.  In the case where you change the setting after seeing the error, you are not actually changing anything on existing ServicePoint instances, including the instance associated with the connection used by WCF in this case.

In your Sample code you are calling `ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint` to try to find the correct ServicePoint.  However, `FindServicePoint` has several overloads and it is easy to use that API incorrectly.  For instance, `FindServicePoint` will try to take into account things http/https, the host you are connecting to, your proxy configuration, etc.  If you are not providing the correct parameters to `FindServicePoint`, you can easily end up getting the wrong ServicePoint returned to you and your settings will not be applied to the `ServicePoint` you intended to change.

I would recommend that you use the `FindServicePoint` overload that takes an `IWebProxy object` to ensure that you get the right `ServicePoint`.  In most cases, you should be able to pass in `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` as the `IWebProxy` object.

Comment: I pass `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` to `FindServicePoint` and it work.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN documentation of ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue,

Changing the value of this property does not affect existing ServicePoint objects. Only new ServicePoint objects created after the change are affected. Therefore changing the value on the existing WCF client will have no effect. You need to create a new WCF client, then call GetData()